# How can I output all of the ID's stored inside of a declared ::text[]

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to mass insert a replicated record for stress testing the application.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    f text[];
BEGIN
    FOR counter IN 1..5 LOOP
        WITH success_insert AS (
            WITH appointment AS (
                SELECT * FROM scheduler_appointments LIMIT 1
            )
            INSERT INTO scheduler_appointments (id, schedule_id, call_id, identifier, name, starts_at, ends_at, created_at, updated_at, type_id)
            SELECT gen_random_uuid(), schedule_id, call_id, gen_random_uuid(), 'TEST FROM MASS PGSQL', starts_at, ends_at, now(), now(), type_id
            FROM appointment
            RETURNING id
        )
        SELECT array_agg(id) INTO f FROM success_insert;
    END LOOP;
    
    SELECT * FROM unnest(f);
END; $$
```

However, I cannot seem to get a list of all the ID's that where created. I instead recieve te following error:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final statement, `SELECT * FROM unnest(f);`, doesn't have an `INTO` clause. I assume the intent is to return all of the inserted `id`s; however, when that last statement is run, `f` will only have the `id` from the last pass through the loop. There's no need to use PLPGSQL. The following SQL will generate `scheduler_appointments` and return an array of the `id`s:

```
WITH appointment AS (
  SELECT * FROM scheduler_appointments LIMIT 1
),
success_insert AS (
  INSERT INTO scheduler_appointments (id, schedule_id, call_id, identifier, name, starts_at, ends_at, created_at, updated_at, type_id)
  SELECT gen_random_uuid(), schedule_id, call_id, gen_random_uuid(), 'TEST FROM MASS PGSQL', starts_at, ends_at, now(), now(), type_id
    FROM appointment CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,5) s(counter)
    RETURNING id
)
SELECT array_agg(id)
  FROM success_insert;
```